# flask python query syntax

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I have a flask project to make query to retrieve the data from the database. I am unsure of the syntax needed to use (SQL equivalent of) 'where'.

```
search_results = search_results.filter(
    (Document).distinct(Document.filename)
        .where(Category.id=1)
        .count)>0))
    .order_by(id.desc())
```

When I use that code, it reports a syntax error.

Comment: parentheses mismatch

Comment: You seem to be using an ORM for your database, but did not state which one.

Comment: @KlausD. could you give an example of how the syntax looks like? or refer me to a documentation? 
@YangHG: ```search_results = search_results.filter((Document).distinct(Document.filename).order_by(id.desc())``` works though